# Pine V5 - Alert on Crossing RSI and Crossing MACD

Tags: pine-script-v5

How can I create an alert or a script mixing 2 different indicators?
Alert on RSI Crossing and MACD Crossing (MACD crossing after the RSI will give that confirmation).
Thank you in advance for your help.

I don't know how to create an alert mixing 2 indicator so will learn by that

Answer (score 0):

You should use a script to do that.
Install the RSI indicator and the MACD indicator, the copy paste their two code in your new indicator script.
Detect the variables have value for you and test for their crossover or crossunder.
Then in your script you can use :

```
alert(message, freq)
```

To create an alert when your conditions are met.
Do not forget to activate the alert on the chart side to make it pop up.